# i18n in iOS Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, internationalization, fetched-property

I'm working on a localized schema for iOS. I have different Entities that can have translated fields, so for each one I create a *Translation* entity. There is always a one-many relation between the two entities, allowing me to add new languages in the future, and I can access the translations via **Entity.translations**. So far so good.

```
Entity
EntityTranslation
```

1) First of all, I would like to know if an approach like that sounds good. Is the solution I will use in a pure SQL environment so I suppose I can follow that path.

2) Then... I would like to just use `Entity.text` for showing the appropriate text for the user (via `NSLocale preferredLanguages`). As `translations` returns a `NSSet` then one option will be to manually add the attribute to the Entity model, and change the getter:

```
// Entity.h
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * text;

// Entity.m
@synthesize text;

- (NSString *) text
{
  NSString *locale = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];

  NSSet *filteredTranslations = [self.translations filteredSetUsingPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"locale = %@", locale]];
  EntityTranslation *translation = [[filteredTranslations allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];

  return translation.text;
}
```

It works, but does it make sense? Can I have performance issues? Is it possible to do something similar using **Fetched properties**? Something tells me that it should be possible but I can't make it work using the Xcode Core Data editor...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not you will have perfomance problems depends how big your database is and how often you're fetching the values. You should run your code through Instruments to check what percentage of CPU time it's costing you, and cache things as necessary.

One tweak I would do is store that NSPredicate object in a static variable, since it will not change often.

If you don't have many records in the table it would be best to fetch the *entire* record set once then save it to an NDDictionary, which you can lookup any time.

However, I think you are making the mistake of using a big complicated system (relational database with an object oriented wrapper) to solve a very simple problem (key value lookup). And complex solutions are almost always slower and more memory hungry than simple ones.

The recommended way to do localization is with a .strings file, and I can't think of any benefits to using core data instead. Do you have 200MB of localized text? If not, then I think it's better to use a .strings file instead of core data.

Comment: +1 - .strings files have proven themselves over the past years.

Comment: Thanks Abhi, but I tried to keep the example simple and, of course, the schema is not so simple :) There are relations with other translatable entities and more fields in Entity an EntityTranslation. Think on the schema of a multilingual blog system (that's not the app, in any case). I don't think a `.string` file is the answer.

Comment: In that case, what you're doing is fine. But you should probably cache the results in an `NSDictionary` if they are being accessed repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks Abhi. What about Fetched properties? I don't know why, but it seems to me that Fetched properties could also be a way of achieving the same result... and being native to Core Data maybe the performance is better... Anyway, note that I say this being unable to make Fetched properties work :)

Comment: I don't see how fetched properties could speed anything up. But then, I've never used them either. How much data do you have in this table? How often does it change?

Comment: Following the blog analogy: some thousand posts (localized) with some hundred authors, and then some metadata, tags, etc. And is not going to change a lot: is more a read database.

Comment: OK, I think what you're doing should be fine. Have you considered having a separate `NSPersistantStore` for each language?

Comment: But are you translating only one information per Entity? What if I would like to translate two columns instead? Is this feasible with the approach above? How?